# Custom allocator using relative address

Tags: c++, stl

How is it possible to use an allocator with relative addressing in C++ standard containers?

```
template<class T>
class Allocator
{
  public:
     typedef uint32_t pointer;
     T& dereference(pointer x) noexcept
     {
         assert(is_valid(x));
         return *(base_ptr + x);
     }

  private:
     T* base_ptr;
     //...
};
```

Motivations:

- A relative address can be kept invariant between different runs. When saving data, just dump `base_ptr` onwards to disk with padding for empty elements. To save disk space, `gzip` the result.
- On x86-64, some containers have huge overhead (consider `std::map<int,int>` where every node needs 32 byte extra, unless you hack the color bit into the least significant bit of one of the pointers, relying on the fact that there are 4 bits that are always zero). With a relative address, the pointer size can be kept smaller, and thus, there is a lower overhead.

There is no custom `dereference` method specified in the interface for allocators. `std::pointer_traits` has `pointer_to`, but that is static, so it cannot access the base pointer.

Comment: `Allocator` doesn't satisfy [allocator requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator). In particular, `uint32_t` is not a `RandomAccessIterator`. You need a class to represent your relative pointer - a so-called ["fancy pointer"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator#Fancy_pointers)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That is what I ask, how to I create such a pointer type, and corresponding allocator.

Comment: The last link I gave mentions [boost::interprocess::offset_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html), which looks similar to what you are trying to do. Boost is open source - if you can't use it directly, you can at least see how they do things.